# jQuery - Are animations and jQuery scripts in general faster in IE?

Tags: jquery, firefox, performance

My pages use jQuery and these are very fast in IE and Chrome. In Firefox 3 animations and other scripts are definitely slower, even if compared with IE6.
I read that jQuery is optimized for IE. 
Is this the only reason? Are you experiencing similar problems?
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be that you have addons installed that are slowing down Firefox?  Firebug could definitely make Fx3 slower than you would expect.